# Create a custom exception using C#

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to override the System.Exception class with my own exception class. I would like to add the parameter "code".

I would want to do this:

```
throw new MyException(code, "message");
```

Then catch the exception using something like this:

```
catch (MyException e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.code)
}
```

**Update:** The problem was that I needed to catch the exception as "(MyException e)" instead of "(Exception e)"

This is my code so far:

```
public class MyException : System.Exception
{
    public String ErrorCode = "";

    public MyException() : base()
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message, string code) : base(message)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = code;
    }
    public MyException(string message, Exception inner, string code) : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = code;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error that "System.Exception does not contain a definition for 'ErrorCode'...". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you accidentally have `catch (Exception e)` instead of `catch (MyException e)`

Comment: Indeed Rob, the class compiles just fine on it's own.

Comment: OT: You're swapping the arguments in the call.

Comment: Tom: pinpoint the line and make sure you post the exact code that produces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have test your code,the exception class is right,but the catch is wrong.My test code is this.

```
        catch (MyException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed I was trying to catch the error as a "exception" instead of "MyException"

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is `ErrorCode` and not `Code`.
Also, make that a public readonly property.

EDIT:

```
catch (MyException e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode)
}
```

Comment: The error message states that it's `ErrorCode` that's missing.

Comment: @svick: Please take a look at the accepted answer. When downvoting, please help me understand the reason. Thanks.

Comment: I think your answer doesn't actually answer the question, because that's not what the problem was. Of course, correctly answering questions like this requires a crystal ball, which is why I *did not* downvote your answer.

Comment: @svick: Thanks for not downvoting. What do you think the problem was other than wrong code pasted by OP? If the question is wrong, it should be deleted. Isn't it?

Comment: The problem was catching `Exception` instead of `MyException`, the OP says that in the update to the question. I think you're right that this question should be deleted, which is why I already voted to close it.